# Wordpress menu items not clickable - No URLs in anchor tag

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a strange issue regarding a Wordpress menu.

Menu items will get added to the menu list but they are not clickable and do not have any URL associated with their anchor  tags.

So far I've tried disabling all plugins and changing themes but the problem persists. I also resaved the permalinks to see if it would fix the problem. Finally, deleting all menu items and rebuilding the menu did nothing either.

Here is the site: https://www.kidsplayandcreate.com

It is the primary menu that is not clickable. And the mobile version of the menu doesn't work either.

Additionally, it doesn't matter how the menu item is added, as a Page, Custom Link or otherwise. It has the same result.

Comment: As i can see there is google ad error in your site..

"VM415 adsbygoogle.js:69 Uncaught O {message: "adsbygoogle.push() error: Only one AdSense head tag supported per page"

Try to  remove unnecessary, duplicate ad codes and just keep one code in <head> ... </head>.

Comment: Can you show us the Menu in Wordpress? In the Dashboard > Appearance > Menus
If you could expand some of them as well...

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I'll try this and see what happens

@Fresz Here is a link to a screenshot of the menu section in Wordpress. https://www.kidsplayandcreate.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/image_2021-08-10_145107.png Whenever I add a page, it automatically turns into a "Custom Link" with no URL/href input available.

Comment: I would suggest doing proper troubleshooting on this. Disable all plugins, change the theme to default, etc. and see if the issue is still there. Make sure everything is updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

The href property does not exist in the a tag
[google chrome developer tools image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6HfW.png)
The first step is to check the WordPress log error file

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for the answert, but please read [How To Answer Well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers